# Laravel Get Config Variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In `Laravel 5.0` I have set in `config/app.php` this:

```
return [
//...
'languages' => ['en','it'],
//...
]
```

Then, I have a blade wrapper in `resources/views/frontend/includes/menus/guest.blade.php`

```
@foreach (Config::get('languages') as $lang => $language)
```

But, Laravel says that foreach has no valid argument, which means that `Config::get('languages')` returns `null`.
I can't set custom variables in `app.php`?

Answer (score 44):

You need to change it to:

`@foreach (Config::get('app.languages') as $lang => $language)`.

Treat the first segment of your lookup as the files under `/config`, in this case `app.php` corresponds to `Config::get('app.*')`

If it wasn't obvious, you can use the helper function `config()` rather than `Config::get()` as well.

Comment: Have you cached your config? `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Thank you, I did it and now work. However, config in cache??I would prefer Cake to Laravel...

Comment: Now I have "No hint path defined for [cookieConsent]. "

Comment: I promise you, in the long run, you'll prefer Laravel. 5.0 is quite old now. If you can, use 5.5 It is the latest LTS version

Comment: Now the last error:FatalThrowableError in ProviderRepository.php line 119:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::isDeferred()

Answer (score 41):

Laravel has a helper function for config which allows you to avoid instantiating a `Config` instance each time you access a value.

Simply use:

```
config('app.languages');
```

Comment: What is the most common way to test code that uses an environment variable in this way. Normally i would guess dependency injection, however i don't see how that would work here.

Answer (score 4):

```
$languages = config('app.languages');

print_r($languages);
```

Comment: This only duplicates Luke's much earlier answer.